# Keep getting an error when trying to use !duplicated function in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I have imported an xlsx document into R, and I have found several duplicates in the document. When I try to delete those duplicates using !duplicated function, it keeps giving me the following error:

Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
ℹ Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
x Input has size 30 but subscript `!duplicated(export)` has size 33376.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
cb<-read.csv("120Water Request_KE.csv")
export <- read_xlsx("Anderson, IN _ Ziptility Export_KE.xlsx")

cb<-clean_names(cb)
export<-clean_names(export)

export <- export[!duplicated[[export, ]
```

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your response. Correct, it has 30 columns.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
export <- export[!duplicated(export),]
```

or

```
library(tidyverse)
export <- export %>%
  distinct(., .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple syntax error.

It's difficult to rewrite your code without having access to your dataset, but the syntax you're looking for is probably this:

```
export[!duplicated(export, by = "column_name"),]
```

Just change your square brackets to round ones and specify which column you want it to check.

Comment: `by` is not an argument of `base::duplicated`, only of `data.table::duplicated`. Can you make that more clear in the answer?